# Yet Another Java Service Wrapper on Debian

Tags: java, linux, debian, wrapper

I had problems with Yajsw installing a service in Debian I was trying to run a java app called Test.jar, so I have

- Executed `ps –af` command to obtain its PID,
- Run GenConfig.sh to generate wrapper.conf setting /path/GenConfig.sh [PID], all was ok.!
- But when I tried to install it as a Daemon I run /path/installDaemon.sh it thrown me these errors, and doesn’t install it as Daemon.

-

```
 java version "1.6.0_26" 
 Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03) 
 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.1-b02, mixed mode, sharing) 
 Dec 2, 2011 11:45:36 AM org.apache.commons.vfs.VfsLog info 
 INFO: Using "/tmp/vfs_cache" as temporary files store. 
 java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) 
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) 
    at org.rzo.yajsw.boot.WrapperExeBooter.main(WrapperExeBooter.java:43) 
 Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: if (new File('/etc/rc0.d').exists()) return '/etc/rcX.d' else 
 return '/etc/init.d/rcX.d' for class: org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationBinding at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:57) 
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationBinding.getVariable(ConfigurationBinding.java:28) 
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.GInterpolator.evaluate(GInterpolator.java:84) 
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.GInterpolator.interpolate(GInterpolator.java:57) 
    at org.rzo.yajsw.config.YajswConfigurationImpl.resolveContainerStore(YajswConfigurationImpl.java:388) 
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractConfiguration.getString(AbstractConfiguration.java:1085) 
    at org.rzo.yajsw.os.posix.PosixService.init(PosixService.java:186) 
    at org.rzo.yajsw.wrapper.WrappedService.init(WrappedService.java:118) 
    at org.rzo.yajsw.WrapperExe.getService(WrapperExe.java:152) 
    at org.rzo.yajsw.WrapperExe.doInstall(WrapperExe.java:296) 
    at org.rzo.yajsw.WrapperExe.executeCommand(WrapperExe.java:215) 
    at org.rzo.yajsw.WrapperExe.main(WrapperExe.java:175) 
    ... 5 more
```

Thanks a lot

Thomas